# Spring Boot: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: security, spring-boot, access-token, wso2-identity-server

I am doing example of Spring Boot Security with wso2is server from this post https://github.com/angel-git/wso2is-springoauth, when I am trying to access resource with access token I am getting

> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}

I am generating access token by:

> curl -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET-k -d
>   "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" -H
>   "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

and accessing resources by:

> curl -H GET "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN"
>   http://localhost:8080/greeting

I found many solution on stackoverflow but unfortunately could not solve my issue

please help, thank you

Comment: Send bearer tokens using `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN` format

Comment: thanx for reply, still I am getting same problem

Comment: Did you use `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" http://localhost:8080/greeting`? Drop the `GET`

Comment: now it's giving {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Access is denied"}

Comment: You haven't the required roles, i guess

Comment: when I am accessing with curl -H "Authorization: Basic <base64-clientid:clientsecret>" http://localhost:8080/generateKey/, without wso2 authentication I get result. But my requirement is first it will authenticate with wso2 IDP then only user can access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanx to Angel Gavalda who helped me to solved problem. I used following commands to generate access token and access resource

For Generating Access token:-

> curl -k -d
>   'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=yourClientId&client_secret=yourClientSecret'
>   https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

For Accessing Resource:-

> curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
>   http://localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: When I am trying to access resource, I get "Please contact your administrator". Am I using the wrong request url? I tried another url and I get the error message that the op is getting.

Comment: @Jesse How you are accessing the resource?

Comment: @GelSisaed from postman it'll pretty simple. Get the token from wso2 then hit your service by providing the Authz type as Bearer Token.

Answer (score 14):

I was getting the same error message for

```
"curl http://localhost:8080/spring4/beans" :
{"timestamp":1493591079040,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource.","path":"/spring4/beans"}
```

Setting the below property in `application.properties` bypassed the security check & I could use all the acuator endpoints:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: Somehow I doubt that bypassing security is the right answer for someone who is trying to use Spring security.

Comment: Yes, I was just using it for testing.  Have to use tokens, etc. for full security.

Answer (score 1):

When the answer above does not solve this issue change `OAuthConfigurations/RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage` to `false` in the file `api-manager.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because I was not properly authenticating the user in my Authentication filter. Please check if user is ACTUALLY authenticated and the roles are filled properly.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());

System.out.println("Is user authenticated? " + authentication.isAuthenticated())
```