# InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0, jwt

So i have a relatively simple JWT authentication with Spring boot security set up. This includes 3 filters (Jwt, Cors, JwtExceptionHandler) and one Exceptionhandler being registered to HttpSecurity.
Due to Debugging reasons i made the `doFilterInternal` Method of the `JwtRequestFilter` empty. That alone creates no problem. If however the `shouldNotFilter` Method in the same Filter returns `true` (that means the `doFilterInternal` will be skipped) i receive the specified Exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:189)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:140)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at at.techsoft.cocos.security.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:20)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

Here is my `WebSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private ExceptionHandlerFilter exceptionHandlerFilter;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(Path.ROOT + "/authentication/**", "/*","/share/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/console/**").permitAll()
            // Disallow everything else..
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilterConfig(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new JwtRequestFilter(new StandardJwtValidator(tokenUtil, userRepository, jwtUserDetailsService)), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(exceptionHandlerFilter, JwtRequestFilter.class);
}



@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(Path.ROOT + "/authentication/",  "/*", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/console/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");

}
```

And this is the JwtRequestFilter in question:

```
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtRequestFilter.class);

final
IJwtValidator validator;

public JwtRequestFilter(IJwtValidator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

@Override
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {            

  //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(validator.getAuthenticatioNToken(request));


}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return true;
}
}
```

When googling for the exception, almost all of the answers include oauth2 authentication, but i do not use oauth2.

I should add that this particular case should never occur, but i feel like there is some underlying problem that is creating bugs in other parts of the system.

EDIT:
As per request I'll add the application.properties:

```
jwt.secret=javainuse
logging.level.at=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true #i know this shouldn't be used

#database location
#left out for post
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2/
spring.datasource.url=#left out again
```

request headers:

```
> GET /api/v1/groups/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: insomnia/7.0.5
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=199D19CCD05968D3E8CF0C97A1DE2CD5
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0c2FkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTc1NTY0MjcxLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU1NDYyNzF9.dCXO2LFaZy8LTFRCA14gHAhA1kUUSy6pCZ7Joad2z1y1G50PSVC2mPz56odA5LmIHOxhjnZrrxAbGyuX2NWgWQ
> Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone after me looking for the solution:
It was one line of code in the `doFilterInternal` Method. At the end I added

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below mentioned articles, it might help

[Spring Boot: Full authentication is required to access this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612648/spring-boot-full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resource)

[secure-your-spring-restful-apis-with-jwt-a-real-world-example](https://medium.com/emblatech/secure-your-spring-restful-apis-with-jwt-a-real-world-example-bfdd2679db5f)

In your spring-boot project if you have application.properties file or application.yml file share that as well. *Is it a server to server authentication or client to server ?*
*Please share the request header details as well*